# Реализовать select и input в одном поле

Tags: jquery, jstl, jsp, form, forms

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо реализрвать `input` и `selector` в одном поле. При загрузке страницы у меня подгружаются данные в `select` 
Когда пользователь хочет выбрать какие-либо данные в поле но не находит их используя `select` tag он может добавить их вводом с клавиатуры. Можно ли как это реализовать с использованием `Jquery-JavaScript` или `JSP-JSTL` или `Spring forms`?

Получилось так:

select2_e.js

```
//инициализация плагина
(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.select2_e = function () {
        $(this).each(function (n, element) {
            //тут превращаем select в input              
            var $element = $(element),
                choices = $element.find('option').map(function (n, e) {
                    var $e = $(e);
                    return {
                        id: $e.val(),
                        text: $e.text()
                    };
                }),
                width = $element.width(),
                $input = $('<input>', {
                    width: width
                });
            $element.hide().after($input);
            //превратили

            $input.select2({
                query: function (query) {
                    var data = {}, i;
                    data.results = [];

                    // подтставим то что искали

                    if (query.term !== "") {
                        data.results.push({
                            id: query.term,
                            text: query.term
                        });
                    }

                    // добавим остальное

                    for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                        if (choices[i].text.match(query.term) || choices[i].id.match(query.term)) data.results.push(choices[i]);
                    }

                    query.callback(data);
                }
            }).on('change', function () {
                var value = $input.val();
                $element.empty();
                $element.append($('<option>').val(value))
                $element.val(value).trigger('change');
            });;
            return $element;
        });
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Мой html файл:

```
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="select2_e.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
         {
jQuery(function ($) {
    console.log($('.testclass').select2_e().on('change', function () {
        alert(this.value)
    }));
});
         });

</script>

</head>

<body>

<select id='test' class="testclass">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
    <option value="4">test4</option>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

И сss:

```
.testclass {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Все лежит в одной папке. Но почему-то не выподает dropbox с элементами? Я просто новичок с jQuery. Извините.

Comment: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Comment: Но это же просто селекторы. Мне нужен селектор и инпут в одном лице. Я поэтому и расписывал все тут. Я нашел, то что походит на мой вопрос, это просто ищет данные посредством ввода с клавиатуры из самого селектора. Если их не находит пишет no matches found. Но и ничего не вставляет в поле. Мне нужно, если не нашел, вставил, что пользователь  ввел.

Comment: вот здесь http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#events не то разве ? или в любом из этих плагинов поменяйте функцию поиска, чтобы добавлять  к списку то что в инпуте.

Comment: От части это работает, я с Jquery не сталкивался ранее. Поэтому  мне трудно понять этот код. Если к примеру убрать селектор сверху и оставить только input и позволить выбирать или добавлять только одно значение.Что от туда нада отсечь?

Comment: я бы посоветовал использовать jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: @IVsevolod его тоже надо допиливать чтобы он в select вставлял нужное значение (в примере не вставляет)

Comment: Оно подключается, но почему-то поиск стал регистрозависимым.

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я думаю вы не осилите это, в общем нужный вам функционал для select2 был описан [здесь](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/100)

я немножко подправил и получил вот такое:

```
(function ($) {
    //тут превращаем select в input    
    var id = "test",
        $id = $('#' + id),
        choices = $id.find('option').map(function (n, e) {
            var $e = $(e);
            return {
                id: $e.val(),
                text: $e.text()
            };
        }),
        width = $id.width(),
        realClass = $id.get(0).className,
        realId = $id.get(0).id,

        $input = $('<input>',{width: width});
    $id.after($input);
    $id.hide();
    $id.find('option').remove();
    //превратили

    $input.select2({
        query: function (query) {
            var data = {}, i;
            data.results = [];

            // подтставим то что искали

            if (query.term !== "") {
                data.results.push({
                    id: query.term,
                    text: query.term
                });
            }

            // добавим остальное

            for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                if (choices[i].text.match(query.term) || choices[i].id.match(query.term)) data.results.push(choices[i]);
            }

            query.callback(data);
        }
    }).on('change',function()
          {   
              var value=$input.val();
              $id.empty();
              $id.append($('<option>').val(value))
              $id.val(value).trigger('change');             
          }
         );
})(jQuery);
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x4XQp/)

[в виде плагина select2_e](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x4XQp/10/)

Comment: Cпасибо большое милый человек... Скажите, я добавляю все это в html и создаю tets.css не работает. Как его скомпановать?

Comment: не очень понял проблему, плагин можно положить в select2_e.js, грузить после jquery и select2 насчет css не понял, просто подключайте css какие надо (ну и css от select2)

Comment: Я отредактировал мой вопрос. Посмотрите пожалуйста, что не так. Я новичок в JQuery  и я уже своими силами это все с jsp интегрую. Но это я уже сам! Мне вместо тест необходимо свои аттрибуты подставить. Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: добавьте перед select2_e.js ссылку на select2 и его css: 

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.js

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.css

сразу после jquery

Comment: Cпасибо тебе милый человек. Все работает, ести это не покажется наглостью, то не во всех же броузерах работать будет?

Comment: не проверял, но там ничего сверъестественного нет.

Comment: Респект.
А как в сочетании 
с ajax : {} 
сделать?


Comment: а в чем проблема ? мб. query: не работает с ajax: ? тогда запрос надо делать вместо choices[]

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

```html
<input type="text" list="cars" />
<datalist id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</datalist>
```